# Is there any possibility to open Contacts App in Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Is there any possibility to open Contacts App in Xamarin IOS,

For android the below code worked for me.

```
var activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionInsert);
intent.SetType(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentType);
activity.StartActivity(intent);
```

Where as for IOS I have't find any code can any one have solution for this.

Comment: You can use the `addressbook:` url scheme to open the iOS System Contacts app: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/URLScheme.html

Comment: Alternately, depending on what your use case is, you can use Xamarin Essentials to [pick a contact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/xamarin-forms?tabs=windows#adding-uitest-support-to-xamarinforms-apps) and return the contact info back to your app.

Comment: @Andrew To add new contact I want to open Contact App, if there is a possibility opening add contact window also fine.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has released two new frameworks, Contacts and ContactsUI, that replace the existing Address Book and Address Book UI frameworks used by iOS 8 and earlier.
You could use these two frameworks to deal with all situation which involve contacts.

To make it clear, I create a simple app to show how to display contact app in ios.
you can  open the contacts app with code like:

```
 public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        picker1.TouchDown += Picker1_TouchDown;
    }

    private void Picker1_TouchDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   //create a picker
        var picker = new CNContactPickerViewController();
        //set the delegate
        picker.Delegate = new ContactPickerDelegate();
        //display picker
        PresentViewController(picker, true, null);
    }
```

The ContactPickerDelegate is what you need to create and used to respond to the user's interaction with the picker.
The code is like:

```
 public class ContactPickerDelegate: CNContactPickerDelegate
    {
        #region Constructors
        public ContactPickerDelegate ()
        {
        }

        public ContactPickerDelegate (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region Override Methods
        public override void ContactPickerDidCancel (CNContactPickerViewController picker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("User canceled picker");

        }

        public override void DidSelectContact (CNContactPickerViewController picker, CNContact contact)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Selected: {0}", contact);
        }

        public override void DidSelectContactProperty (CNContactPickerViewController picker, CNContactProperty contactProperty)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Selected Property: {0}", contactProperty);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**Screenshots：**

[image]

[image]

For more information, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/contacts

Comment: This is for pick the contact but I need to open the contact app, is there any possibility for that.

Comment: check this question https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15c3112a-35f7-4569-89fe-685eed239f17/how-can-i-open-phone-contacts-in-xamarin-forms?forum=xamarinios